# vba excel look up with variable

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

Every month I update my new aged balance, and then I create automatically a new sheet with a macro, which will filter customer.

So here are my current sheets:
[image: So here are my current sheets]

Each month, I'm following my customers's payments by adding comments at Column 10.

On the latest page, I want to add old comments after the column 10 so at column 11,12,13 there will be old comments... So there will be as many new columns as there are sheets of customers.

Old comments are in sheets "clients 2019-01-31" and "clients 2019-02-28"
I want to add them in "clients 2019-03-30"

For doing that, i think using Vlookup was the best plan. But looks like I have too many variable, it doesn't work:

> Error 1004.

I really tried much things, like declaring sheets before each cells, activating the sheet just before.
Worksheets(Sheets.Count).Activate

I can't get it working. If something isn't clear, please tell me I'll try to explain it better.

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim nbCustomer ' Customer Number, this value is not fix in my whole program
nbCustomer = 244

Dim numCol ' Column Number
numCol = 11

Dim nbws ' Sheets number
nbws = Sheets.Count

nbws = nbws - 1 ' Because we don't need to lookup on the last page

     While (nbws > 1)

         Dim numL ' Line Number
         numL = 2


              While (numL <= nbCustomer)
              nbCustomer = nbCustomer + 10
              Worksheets(Sheets.Count).Cells(numL, numCol) = Application.VLookup(Cells(numL, 1), Sheets(nbws).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(nbCustomer, 10)), 10, False)
              numL = numL + 1
              nbCustomer = nbCustomer - 10
              Wend

         numCol = numCol + 1
         nbws = nbws - 1 ' we will look up our data on the previous sheet

     Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: I think the issue is `Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(nbCustomer, 10)`. `Range()` expects its parameters to be strings, not ranges.

Comment: I have an other macro for the which it is working like that. ( not in a Vlookup ).

Comment: It worked it for exemple : `Worksheets(Sheets.Count).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(nbClients, 10)).AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=">1", Operator:=xlAnd`